# Use tcpdump to find interface errors

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I looking for what's causing dropped packets on an interface:

```
      RX packets:9064457 errors:0 dropped:4736 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6388938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
```

I know it's not the firewall because it gets dropped before it would even reach that.

I made a dumpfile with:
          tcpdump -n -s0 -w interface_errors.pcap -i eth1

Then I try to analyze (replay) this dump with tshark/tcpdump:

```
      tshark -r interface_errors.pcap not ip and not ipv6 and not arp
```

With this basically all I get is some LLDP Multicast, IPX packets from some windows machines. Is there any way to do further debugging to determine the root cause of these errors on the interface?

Thanks

Comment: Those drops seem more likely to me to be buffer underruns. There might be too much traffic, or a bad network driver, a shared IRQ, whatever. If I'm right you won't be able to sniff them.

Comment: Hello. I ran iptraf and the average is like 2-400kbit/s on that interface (which is gbit). I doubt it's because of too much traffic.

Comment: If your system is using lots of CPU, it could also drop packets because it'll hit ISR timeouts.

Comment: How fast does that counter increase? Keep in mind it is a cumulative counter

Comment: Hello. The system is mostly idling, it increases slowly I just got errors of it because of the nagios monitoring system but yesterday the server was rebooted (manually) and I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with the link there.

Comment: Typical reasons are checksum errors, and too large ("[jumbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame))") or too small ethernet frames, look out for those. You can probably ask Wireshark to filter for ethernet frames with bad FCS, or larger than MTU+22.